# How I can get the same result using iloc in Pandas in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Pandas dataframe I can get the first 1000 rows with `data.iloc[1:1000,:]`. How I can do it in PySpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.limit(1000)` to get 1000 rows from your dataframe. Note that Spark does not have a concept of index, so it will just return 1000 random rows. If you need a particular ordering, you can assign a row number based on a certain column, and filter the row numbers. e.g.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('col_to_order'))) \
        .filter('rn <= 1000')
```

Comment: I wanna put it in a for loop. and use whole data in smaller parts

Comment: I think you're trying to split the dataframe. In that case, you can try `dfs = df.randomSplit([0.5,0.5])`, which gives you a list of split dataframes. You can change the numbers in the list, e.g. if you want to split 4 dataframes, you can use `[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]`.

Comment: should I write this: `df1,df2=df.randomSplit([0.5,0.5])` ?

Comment: you can just write `dfs = ...` and access the split dataframes using `df[0], df[1]`, etc. `dfs` is a list of dataframes.

Comment: `Transitions.randomSplit` give me an empty datasets. why is that?

Comment: maybe your dataframe is empty

Comment: No it is not, I checked it

Comment: how many rows are there? and what list did you pass to the`randomSplit` function?